# can a Compound Component start activity for a result?

Tags: android

is it possible to create a compound components encapsulate the logic of starting activity for result?

for exemple, if i want to create some setting page (Activity) with the ability to let the user pick a audio file, image file, and some contact. 
why wouldnt i be able to encapsulate each idea into a separate compound component who would do its job independently? for instance the picking audio exemple could run an implicit intent for getting user's audio choice, then when the choise is made, it could show the result on a TextView that is contained within this compund component and maybe let the user adjust its volume and stuff.

I dont get why would Google design it this way that in my use case i would have to implement ALL this logic in one activity class? (or have an activity  for each of those uses which is something i dont want).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement all of the logic in a single activity class. I believe the easiest way would be to create an interface that an activity that wants to support this element has to implement. You provide a reference to this interface when creating this component.

You can then have a callback mechanism that will notify the component when the result from the audio file picker activity is ready (after `onActivityResult()`). It's not easy, but it's definitely possible to decouple a component from a specific activity.

Comment: oh, that is actually a good idea, even though in my opinion it still is a workaround for a bad design decision made by google

Comment: Well, I think you can't make everyone happy :) . It's definitely not simple, but then again, I don't think it's the most common use case either. Not a lot of people go out of their way to ensure reusability.

Comment: Also, if you find an alternate way of getting this to work, feel free to share :)